# Script /.bat para matar determinado processo em todos os usuários logados no computador

Tags: batch, script, processo

Bom pessoal, meu problema é o seguinte: Tenho um processo que se chama `gdc.exe`. Se um usuário estiver com esse processo aberto e outro usuário fazer login na máquina e tentar executar o programa que gera esse mesmo processo, ele não consegue abrir o programa. Preciso de um `.bat` ou um script que mate todos os processos abertos com esse nome, não somente no usuário que está utilizando (de preferência que não exija diretos administrativos), mas em todos que estão logados na máquina. Já procurei por aí mas não achei nada que me ajudasse.

Answer (score 1):

Você consegue matar todos os processos com o nome `gdc.exe` você pode usar o comando [`taskkill`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725602(v=ws.10).aspx):

```
taskkill /f /im gdc.exe
```

Para que o `taskkill` finalize os processos rodando sob outros usuários você *precisa* executar o comando como administrador.

Comment: pois é, sei que dá pra usar o taskkill, mas tem algum jeito de criar um bat com as credenciais de administrador para o usuário poder rodar quando quiser?

Comment: @Mathi901 Você não havia pedido isso. Edite sua pergunta e adicione essa informação.

Comment: @Mathi901 o problema de criar um bat assim é que qualquer um pode abrir ele e ver as credenciais do admin, e se você criar um arquivo bat que só pode ser executado pelo admin tbm não irá resolver seu problema

Comment: não existe algum comando para ao menos criptografar a senha?

Answer (score 0):

crie um outro bat e use isso, se sua rede tiver um domínio pode ajudar

```
runas /env /savecred /nome-do-usuario-administrador@dominio "caminho do bat que mata o processo"
```

depois de executado basta você digitar a senha do Administrador uma vez e depois não 
ira ser necessário digitar novamente.

Comment: @Mathi901, utilizando Runas não resolve seu problema?